# Socket Whitelist IP aceito conexão C#

Tags: c#, socket

Estou tentando fazer um sistema Socket (Servidor -> <- Client), porem quero fazer uma whitelist de ip que podem ser aceito na conexão do cliente para o servidor, porem não sei como, resumido quero fazer sistema onde o Servidor 
verifica se o ip que esta no "whitelist" que vai ser uma array, se o ip
tiver la vai a conexão do cliente vai ser aceita se não tiver o ip la
não vai connectar!.

Server:

```
        public Client(Socket ClientSocket)
    {
        //Client = this;
        this.ClientSocket = ClientSocket;
        ClientStream = new NetworkStream(ClientSocket);

        EndPoint = (IPEndPoint)ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;

        ClientThread = new Thread(ClientCallback);
        ClientThread.Start();

        LogFactory.GetLog(this).LogInfo("Client <{0}> connected to the server!", EndPoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Só criar uma Lista com os ips permitidos, e quando chegar a conexão verificar se a lista contém o ip que conectou:

```
    private void teste(Socket ClientSocket)
    {
        List<string> whiteList = new List<string>
        {
            "192.168.0.1",
            "192.168.0.2",
            "192.168.0.3",
            "192.168.0.4",
            "192.168.0.5",
            "192.168.0.6"                
        };

        string _ip = ((IPEndPoint)ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

        if (whiteList.Contains(_ip))
        {
            //permite
        }
        else
        {
            ClientSocket.Disconnect(false);
        }

    }
```